# An illegal reflective access operation has occurred when runnodes

Tags: java, corda

I'm trying to run my corda nodes but I'm facing a strange issue, the nodes are getting started correctly as you can see in the logs

```
C:\Repositorio\cordapp-template-kotlin\build\nodes>runnodes --log-to-console --logging-level=DEBUG
Starting nodes in C:\Repositorio\cordapp-template-kotlin\build\nodes
Starting corda.jar in C:\Repositorio\cordapp-template-kotlin\build\nodes\Notary on debug port 5005
Starting corda.jar in C:\Repositorio\cordapp-template-kotlin\build\nodes\PartyA on debug port 5006
Starting corda-webserver.jar in C:\Repositorio\cordapp-template-kotlin\build\nodes\PartyA on debug port 5007
Starting corda.jar in C:\Repositorio\cordapp-template-kotlin\build\nodes\PartyB on debug port 5008
Starting corda-webserver.jar in C:\Repositorio\cordapp-template-kotlin\build\nodes\PartyB on debug port 5009
Started 5 processes
Finished starting nodes
```

Howerver when it opens the 5 consoles to actually run the Web services and the nodes as well, is where it happens.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by Capsule (file:/C:/Repositorio/cordapp-template-kotlin/build/nodes/PartyB/corda.jar) to field com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.mbsInterceptor
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of Capsule
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5008
[quasar] ERROR: java/lang/Thread
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkFileAndClose(MethodDatabase.java:344)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkClass(MethodDatabase.java:324)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.getOrLoadClassEntry(MethodDatabase.java:183)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.isMethodSuspendable0(MethodDatabase.java:194)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.isMethodSuspendable(MethodDatabase.java:161)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.InstrumentMethod.isSuspendableCall(InstrumentMethod.java:231)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.LabelSuspendableCallSitesClassVisitor$1.visitMethodInsn(LabelSuspendableCallSitesClassVisitor.java:64)
        at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:123)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:94)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.JavaAgent$Transformer.transform(JavaAgent.java:209)
        at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(Unknown Source)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)
[quasar] ERROR: java/lang/Thread
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkFileAndClose(MethodDatabase.java:344)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkClass(MethodDatabase.java:324)
```

printscreen of the consoles:
[image: printscreen of the consoles]

Has anyone faced the same issue? I don't have a clue how to debug it.

Comment: Are you running an existing CorDapp or your own? Are you running it using `deployNodes` and `runNodes`?

Comment: It happens with the default cordapp and also with my own. I think is something related with my laptop

Comment: Can you check your Java version? `java -version` from the terminal. This can be related to Java 9.

Comment: java 10.0.1 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running Java 10. Corda is only supported on versions 8u131+ of the Oracle JDK 8 JVM.

You can see the required Java version here: https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html.

Answer (score 1):

After changing Project SDK under `File > Project Structure... to 1.8.0_242`, you may also need to **unlink** and **link** Gradle again by:

1. right-clicking your Gradle project on Gradle window and click `Unlink Gradle Project`
2. Go to `File > Close Project`
3. Open your current project again and you will see a message `IntelliJ IDEA found a Gradle build script`
4. Click `Import Gradle Project` underneath it and wait for it to complete.

I wrote this because I accidentally import Gradle on Java 11 environment. However, after changing project SDK I still wasn't able to run unit test due to `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` error.